# QGIS change icon in legend

Tags: qgis, legend, icon

could I change the icon of my legend in the mapcomposer?
I want other icons for my layers in the legend then in the project.

I use the Version 3.4.8 LTR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is only available in QGIS 3.14 and later. For earlier versions, you can workaround it by duplicating the layer, hiding the second copy and changing its symbol, and then only including this second version in the legends.